# Passing variable number of strings to MATLAB function from varagin

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions, cell-array

I have a function where I am receiving parameters as part of a `varargin` parameter. However, within that function is another function call using `varargin`. How can I pass the contents of the first `varargin` to the nested function without ended up with a cell array of cell arrays?

That is, given the following code:

```
function foo(varargin)
    bar(varargin)
end

function bar(varargin)
    % Do something with varargin
end

foo('ab', 'cdef')
```

the `varargin` in `bar(varargin)` is a 1x1 cell array containing the 1x2 cell array `{'ab', 'cdef'}`.

I'm trying instead to write something where:

```
foo('ab', 'cdef')
```

can give a `bar(varargin)` call where the `varargin` is just a 1x2 cell array `{'ab', 'cdef'}`.

How can I transfer the contents of the `varargin` cell array in the `foo` call to just be individual parameters in the `bar` call?

Comment: can you just do `bar(varargin{:});`?

Comment: Yes. Yes I can. That was painfully simple. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'll write the answer so you can mark it as accepted

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) does not accept string inputs

Comment: @excaza: I added a definition to make that clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply bring the elements out of the cell array by using the `{:}` colon argument

```
function foo(varargin)
    bar(varargin{:});
end
```